# MacOS Electron JS Installation Missing Path Link

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

After running `npm install electron@latest` on MacOS with and without sudo permissions, I can't use the `electron` command. The error codes in the log file are:

```
117 error code ELIFECYCLE
118 error errno 1
119 error electron@5.0.4 postinstall: `node install.js`
119 error Exit status 1
120 error Failed at the electron@5.0.4 postinstall script.
120 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely  additional logging output above.
121 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Is this a bug (because I am reading similar errors [on GitHub](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt/issues/258) but these are closed now)? Or is there a way to repair or further force the installation?

> I am pretty new to NPM/ Electron so it could just be that that's how it's normal and I lack experience, but it worked fine on my Windows machine, so I was wondering. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed electron js with command `sudo npm install -g electron@latest --unsafe-perm=true` on Mac. I can run the `electron` command.